# Python cx_freeze setup script not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, cx-freeze

I have a python script that I'd like to freeze. I made the `cx_freeze` script, and ran it. The `.exe` works well, but in the frozen script I open a `.html` file. When the file opens the webbrowser gives me the error "`File not found: Firefox cannot find the file at /c:/blah/blah/blah/somefile.html`"

As I understand it, this is because `cx_freeze` is confusing my OS between linux and Windows. However, I'm not sure this is it because I have the code

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
   base = "Win32GUI"
```

In my setup file. Does anyone know what's going on?

My entire setup file is

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
   base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "someexe",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "someexe description",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("someexe.py", base=base)])
```

copied from [the cx_freeze distutils page](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html) and edited to fit my needs.

Comment: I mean to ask you on your previous question whether the script runs properly before being frozen, though I presume it does.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is in your script itself, not the setup file. Also, what is the actual error, that could help. The /blah/blah/blah may hint to what's going on

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Everything worked perfectly before being frozen, yes.

Comment: @Parker The script ran well. Only after being frozen did it fail. The actual error is cx_freeze is converting my windows filepaths to linux filepaths. :/

Comment: *Everything worked well, until I added a `os.chdir('c:/blah/blah/activefolder')` to the top of my script. I added the `os.chdir` because the batch that was calling the script was starting it in the wrong directory to access local files. I have it looking for local files because that's much more flexible than coding the complete filepaths. Anyway, after I set the active directory, it started looking for a path starting with `/c:/` rather than `c:/`, and I don't know why.

Comment: The actual code could still help, it may be the way you're calling a file

Comment: @Parker Okay figured out. Nothing to do with what I thought. It's a permissions thing. Fixed that, now I have the issue that it cannot read the support files. (this is in `program files (x86)`)

Comment: I found the real problem, so I will ask about that as a separate question.

Comment: @CollegeGamer, I guess your real problem had to do with your script.  Generally don't hard code a path if you want to freeze your script.  Path should be relative to your script or give the user a way to select the path.  Would suggest to close or delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `os.chdir('C:/path/to/dir')`, you should be using `os.chdir('C:\path\to\dir')`. It's an error in your script, not your cx_freeze setup file.

Comment: `os.chdir` calls `SetCurrentDirectoryW`, which translates slashes to backslashes.